# Откуда берутся фильтры в CNN?

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, машинное-зрение

проконсультируйте пожалуйста по следующему моменту в работе свертки:
Вот у нас допустим есть на входе цветное изображение 100×100×3
Мы продаем его на свёрточный слой
Инициализировали фильтры (пусть 16 фильтров (3,3) с нулевым паддингом) и получили выход 100×100×16
Подали в активацию, получили те же 100×100×16
Подали в макспулинг, получили 50×50×16
Подали в следующий слой с количеством фильтров 32, выход должен быть 50×50×32
Собственно вопрос: как из 16 фильтров мы должны получить 32?
Мы должны инициализировать заново новые 16 фильтров, или инициализировать только 16, сохранив предыдущие 16?

Comment: Покажите **конкретную** конфигурацию нейросети (не в виде пересказа). Вообще там дальше `dense` слои должны вроде бы идти, вы ничего не путаете? Хотя бывает, что и повышают число слоёв и информации, весь вопрос как это соединить. Если соединять все нейроны слоя со всеми нейронами предыдущего слоя, то вообще нет проблемы, можно на очередном слое делать любое количество, увеличивать, уменьшать, проблем нет никаких (ну, кроме вычислительной сложности).

Comment: Я про передачу выхода с одного сверточного слоя через активацию и макспулинг на другой, но кажется вопрос уже решён

Comment: Сам же написал про разницу между ядром фильтра и самим фильтром при многоканальном изображении, сам же про это забыл
Да, теперь я въехал в историю
На вход подаётся 100×100×3, далее мы имеем 16 фильтров с 3 ядрами каждый, где размер ядра—3×3, выходом является матрица 100×100×16, то есть 16 карт признаков, где карта признаков—результат применения фильтра к исходному изображению, размер каждой карты признаков 100×100×1 (три ядра одного фильтра складываются поэлементно)
Затем у нас идёт активация каждого значения в этой выходной матрице, после макспулинг и выход с размером 50×50×16

Comment: Следующая свертка инициализирует 32 фильтра, включающих по 16 ядер каждый
После применения каждого фильтра к исходной матрице значения всех 16 ядер для каждого фильтра поэлементно складываются, образуя матрицу 50×50×1, но так как фильтров таких у нас 32, получаем выход 50×50×32
И так далее